# edit month and day of date simultaneously

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to modify the day and year of dates, however running into some issues when I do these operations sequentially because of leap years:

```
newDay = 5
newMonth = 2
dts = as.Date(c('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-29'))
month(dts) = newMonth
day(dts) = newDay
# [1] "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05" NA
```

Is there any way to access the month and day at the same time so this returns:

```
[1] "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05"
```

Comment: was this the answer you were looking for or did I not fully understand what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't worry about months/dates and simply run a `str_replace` you should be fine:

```
library(stringr)
dts <- as.Date(c('2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-03-29'))
print(dts)
library(stringr)
dts <- str_replace(dts, "-..-..", "-02-05")
print(dts)
```

Output:

```
# print(dts)
# "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" "2019-03-29"
#
# print(dts)
# "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can make use of `POSIXlt` class to simultaneously change the 'month' and 'day'

```
f1 <- function(date, dy, mth) {
   new_date <- unclass(as.POSIXlt(date))
   new_date[c("mon", "mday")] <- list(rep(mth -1, length(date)), 
                   rep(dy, length(date)))
   class(new_date) <- "POSIXlt"
   as.Date(new_date)
   
  
  }

f1(dts, 5, 2)
#[1] "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to really have two operations in parallel. A minor change to you code is to swap the lines for `day` and `month`, e.g.,

```
f <- function(dts, newM, newD) {
  day(dts) <- newD
  month(dts) <- newM
  dts
}
```

and you will see

```
> f(dts, newMonth, newDay)
[1] "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05" "2019-02-05"
```

Comment: @akrun Well...That's weird. I got this `> f(dts, 3, 29)
[1] "2019-03-29" "2019-03-29" "2019-03-29"`

Comment: May be it is related to the locale, but the `POSIXlt` is working for me `f1(dts, newDay, newMonth)#
[1] "2019-03-29" "2019-03-29" "2019-03-29"`

Answer (score 0):

```
dts <- lubridate::make_date(year(dts), 2, 5)
```